# Flutter: Creating an add_close AnimatedIcons

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation

I'd like to create a beginning icon as `Icon.add` and end icon which is `Icon.close` in the `AnimatedIcon` widget. For e.g. their is a prebuilt animation of `add_event` that corresponds to begin animation = `add` and end animation = `event`. I'd like to change the end animation to be `Icon.close`. It's unclear how to do this as there's no documentation readily available for creating custom animations. The most relevant code I could find is: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/e10df3c1a65f9d7db3fc5340cffef966f7bd40a6/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/animated_icons/data/add_event.g.dart. I believe I should use `vitool`. How can I go about creating new animations?

Comment: What do you mean by `create an add_close animated icon `?

Comment: @mFeinstein I'd like to create a beginning icon as `Icon.add` and end icon of `Icon.close` in the `AnimatedIcon` widget. For e.g. their is a prebuilt animation of `add_event` that corresponds to begin animation = `add` and end animation = `event`. I'd like to change the end animation to be close.

Comment: Ok, understood, add this to your question's description.

Comment: Seems like the vitool is not intended for public use its mentioned here in readme: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/tree/master/dev/tools/vitool

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So I had some free time and this is something many people might want to use at some point as we do not have much options for AnimatedIcons that are already given to us.
So I went ahead and built this small package and uploaded it on pub dart that solves what you are looking for.
With this package you can animate any two icons.

Check on pub dart **[animate_icons](https://pub.dev/packages/animate_icons)**

Simply add the package into pubspec.yaml like this:

```
animate_icons:
```

Then use this Widget like this:

```
AnimateIcons(
    startIcon: Icons.add,
    endIcon: Icons.close,
    size: 60.0,
    onStartIconPress: () {
        print("Clicked on Add Icon");
    },
    onEndIconPress: () {
        print("Clicked on Close Icon");
    },
    duration: Duration(milliseconds: 500),
    color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
    clockwise: false,
),
```

Comment: Thank you for this. I'm looking for the `AnimatedIconData` object to be outputted. That's why I haven't written a custom animation. Is there anyway to do this using your package?

Comment: @Black sorry but i dont think that'll be possible. 
All the animatedIcons that are provided to us are custom made Animated Vectors if you need only that than i think you'll have to build that.
Other way i can suggest is that you build animated widget with Flare https://rive.app/ here and than integrate  in your app. 
but still if i were you, I'ld not use the animated icon widget for animated icons that are not provided to us.
If you dont find any way u can still try the plugin. 
this should solve the use case i am sure.

Comment: You saved me big time. Let's meet in the pub later.

Comment: When the icon is in small spaces it does not work, it does not align in the center @AmanMalhotra

Answer (score 6):

Yes, friend, you need to create your own **animation**

I have written code for the situation that you talked about

I used to [Transform](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Transform-class.html) widget , and  [AnimationController](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/animation/AnimationController-class.html)

```
import 'dart:math';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  AnimationController animatedController;
  double _angle = 0;

  @override
  void initState() {
    animatedController =
        AnimationController(vsync: this, duration: Duration(milliseconds: 300));
    animatedController.addListener(() {
      setState(() {
        _angle = animatedController.value * 45 / 360 * pi * 2;
      });
    });
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        home: Scaffold(
            body: Center(
      child: InkResponse(
        onTap: () {
          if (animatedController.status == AnimationStatus.completed)
            animatedController.reverse();
          else if (animatedController.status == AnimationStatus.dismissed)
            animatedController.forward();
        },
        child: Transform.rotate(
          angle: _angle,
          child: Icon(
            Icons.add,
            size: 50,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    )));
  }
}
```

If you need to customize more than this, Take a look at the [AnimatedContainer](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/AnimatedContainer-class.html)

Comment: Thanks, I think that for smaller apps this is more suitable.

Answer (score 2):

if the [simple transition](https://material.io/design/iconography/animated-icons.html#transitions) between the two icons is enough, then [`simple_animated_icon`](https://pub.dev/packages/simple_animated_icon) package might be useful.

```dart
class AnimatedIconButton extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _AnimatedIconButtonState createState() => _AnimatedIconButtonState();
}

class _AnimatedIconButtonState extends State<AnimatedIconButton>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  bool _isOpened = false;
  AnimationController _animationController;
  Animation<double> _progress;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    _animationController =
        AnimationController(vsync: this, duration: Duration(milliseconds: 300))
          ..addListener(() {
            setState(() {});
          });

    _progress =
        Tween<double>(begin: 0.0, end: 1.0).animate(_animationController);
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _animationController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  void animate() {
    if (_isOpened) {
      _animationController.reverse();
    } else {
      _animationController.forward();
    }

    setState(() {
      _isOpened = !_isOpened;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return IconButton(
        onPressed: animate,
        icon: SimpleAnimatedIcon(
          startIcon: Icons.add,
          endIcon: Icons.close,
          progress: _progress,
        ));
  }
}
```